# left_join in R returns and error "Error: Join columns must be present in data" colnames() says that the col names are present

Tags: r, left-join

I am trying to join two data frames using a left_join function. Here is my code:

```
combined <- left_join(APRN_mailing, DOPL_List, by = "ID")
```

I keep receiving the error:

> "Error: Join columns must be present in data."

When I run `colnames()` on both data frames I get:

```
colnames(DOPL_List)
[1]"ID.LAST_NAME.FIRST_NAME.gender.ADDR_LINE_1.ADDR_LINE_2.CITY.STATE.zipcode.EMAIL.LicenseID.ProfessionGroup.Birth_Year"
```

colnames(APRN_mailing)

[1]"ID.LAST_NAME.FIRST_NAME.gender.ADDR_LINE_1.ADDR_LINE_2.CITY.STATE.zipcode.EMAIL.ProfessionGroup.Birth_Year"

It looks to me like I have a column named "ID" in both data frames. I have tried rewriting the code:

```
combined <- left_join(APRN_mailing, DOPL_List, by = c("ID" = "ID")
```

but I get the same result.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: hello @blariviere Could you present a print or reproduce your example? do both data.frames have a column called "ID"?

Comment: It looks as though the data was not read into R correctly, you have one column with a long name, not separate columns. It would help to see a sample of the original file and the command used to read it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you misread the data, your columns are not separated. If you look at the results of colnames () it only returns the name of a variable, which is very long.

Comment: You are right! I fixed it, thanks.